# How can I clear any ufw entries that are not in a list with ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ufw

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ufw_module.html

I have configured Ansible 2 to allow a bunch of ip addresses with ufw with entries like this:

```
  - name: allow from this one computer
    ufw:
      rule: allow
      port: 22
      src: 192.168.5.5
```

However, I would also like to remove any old entries, or entries that got there by mistake.

For example, if an old version had 192.168.8.8, I would like to remove it.  Or if somebody added it manually.

Is there any reasonable way to do that?  I guess if the server is only ever configured by ansible, and when I remove an ip address from the list, I add an entry to remove it, I won't have that problem.

Answer (score 6):

I faced a similar issue when trying to standardise my servers' UFW with Ansible v2.9 after having different rules on each one.

The approach was to `reset` the UFW, which deletes all existing rules, and create the rules I wanted, taking a lot of care about **not locking me outside the server**.

The code:

```
- name: Setup admin production UFW
  hosts: my_hosts
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - block:
      - name: Reset UFW
        ufw: 
          state: reset

      - name: Allow outgoing
        ufw: 
          default: allow
          direction: outgoing

      - name: Disallow ingoing
        ufw: 
          default: deny
          direction: incoming

      - name: Establish regular admin rules
        ufw:
          rule: allow
          direction: in
          port: '5432'
          proto: tcp
          from_ip: '{{ item }}'
        loop:
          - 123.456.789/32
          - 987.654.321/32

      always:
        - name: Grant ssh access
          ufw:
            rule: allow
            direction: in
            port: '22'
            proto: tcp
            from_ip: 321.456.987/32
        
         - name: Enable Firewall
           ufw: 
            state: enabled
```

**Explained step by step**

Notice the `block: always:` parameters. You will set almost all actions inside `block:` and leave `always:` as a security valve so in case of any failure you're sure you'll still have SSH access to your server.

This may also be accomplished with `ignore_errors: yes` at the block level, but I perceive from the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) that is not the 'safest' option.

`Allow outgoing` and `Disallow ingoing` defines general behavior.

Then, you add as many rules as you will, and close with the `always` allowing SSH, and enabling your Firewall, having a safe playbook.

**Recommendation**

I strongly suggest that you **do not** test your UFW playbooks in servers which you will miss if something gets wrong.

Test your UFW playbooks in a single testing server to which you have one or two SSH connections already set up, so if you rule denies all SSH connections, you're still inside and can `ufw allow 22`

Comment: Will there be a short time window when the firewall will be deactivated?

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"An old version had 192.168.8.8, I would like to remove it."*

A: See the parameter [delete](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ufw_module.html#parameter-delete). For example

```yaml
  - name: delete rule
    ufw:
      delete: true
      rule: allow
      port: 22
      src: 192.168.8.8
```

Comment: Yeah but i don't know whixmch entries already exist

Comment: Well, there is no safe remedy when a box has been compromised. You can [reset](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ufw_module.html#parameter-state) ufw, of course. But, I wonder that you ask what to do when you were not able to secure ufw. Shut the box down and bring up a new one.

Comment: I am introducing it gradually to a bunch of manually managed boxes.  So starting with the firewall, but need to clear any manually added entries.  But yeah I will just make another script that does a reset I guess.

Comment: @Alex028502 reset + add all rules is really what you are looking for if you fear some external source might affect the settings. This concure with the goal of Ansible to make idempotent results. Once you are 100% sure Ansible is the only one managing, then you'll just have to remove the reset task.